# Android bitmap decode problem

Tags: android, bitmap, decode

I have a problem with a file retrieved from a server using XML.

The bitmap (a GIF) is base64 encoded then placed inside the XML as a string.
The app gets this string, decodes it to a bitmap, then displays it.

It works fine most of the time, but sometimes the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returns null, with no indication of the problem.

I've copied one of the files that fails via XML (it's repeatable!) as a resource, and it works just fine.

```
    bMapArray = Base64Coder.decode(cd.image); // Decode the encoded string
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fail);
    Log.e("config", bMap.getConfig().name());
    // shows RGB_565, decodes OK and will display
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);           
    Log.e("config", bMap.getConfig().name());           
    // Null config and displays OK for some files, 
    // Fails decodeByteArray for the file matching the one used as a resource and some others
```

I've spent days trying to fathom out the problem with no success. Does anyone have a bright idea?
I'm happy to accept it's a problem with the 64 bit enc/decode process, but with no errors from decodeByteArray I'm not sure what.

Cheers,

Martin.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that downloads bitmaps from a variety of sites - none of which are base64 encoded. Most of the time the bitmaps go through decodeByteArray just fine, but every now and again (eg the default Facebook profile icon) I get back null.

I spent ages trying to figure out what was going on, and in the end concluded (as you also suspect) that it was a bug in GIF handling in decodeByteArray.

If you search here (and elsewhere) for "android bitmap gif decodebytearray" you can find lots of hints that other people are having the same issue - but I haven't found a authorative bug report.

Comment: Hmmm - converted the file to an array then back using decodebytearray. It still fails, so I think that puts the blame squarley on decodebytearray. Bugger! Any idea where I can find the source? I'll try PNG's as well, although that means more work serverside.  `InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.fail);
         byte [] array = new byte[]{};
         try {
   is.read(array);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
         bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);`

Comment: You can get the decodeByteArray source at http://code.google.com/p/skia/source/checkout.

Answer (score 0):

There are three very obvious things that can go wrong here.

1) The way the image is added to the XML before sending - check to see if it's being encoded properly

2) The transmission process - make sure that the transmission isn't being truncated, especially with buffered input streams

3) The parsing of the data from the XML recieved - again check that the string is parsed back out properly.

The most likely candidate is transmission.  Does the size of image affect the results you are seeing?  If it is only recieving part of the data it will fail.